# jmeter test failed with out of memory error

Tags: java, jmeter

When try to run jMeter with 50 or more user it gives OutOfMemoryError:

```
2013/12/18 13:35:15 ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Error processing Assertion  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2013/12/18 13:35:15 ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Error processing Assertion     java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2013/12/18 13:35:15 ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Error processing Assertion  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2013/12/18 13:35:15 ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Error processing Assertion  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2013/12/18 13:35:16 ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed! java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2013/12/18 13:35:17 ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed!
```

I tried to increase the heap size but still getting the same error.
Even i tried to remove all the listeners but nothing changed.

Comment: Is it GUI mode or not? How many listeners do you use? Take a look at these tips http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean

Comment: Another article proposing 12 possibles solutions: https://octoperf.com/blog/2017/10/17/solve-jmeter-out-of-memory-issues/

Answer (score 41):

It looks like that you're just lacking Java Heap Space. It's normal as JMeter by default has a very low heap allocation. It's controllable via `-Xmx` parameter.

There is a line in  `jmeter.bat` or `jmeter.sh` script which recommends launching JMeter as

```
JVM_ARGS="-Xms512m -Xmx512m" jmeter.sh
```

You can try increasing maximum heap until you'll stop receiving these errors. I'd recommend to set it to something like 80% of your hardware RAM.

Also consider [JMeter Performance and Tuning Tips article](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips) to make sure that you disable memory-consuming listeners, don't overscript, use post-processors efficiently, etc.

Answer (score 10):

After the increase, the heap size in bat file remove all listener from the test plan, Then run your script and see the magic.Now you won't get [out of memory error in jmeter](http://asktofolks.com/787/out-of-memory-error-in-jmeter)
Enjoy!

Comment: nice pick, Listeners takes lots of memory +1 for that.

Answer (score 3):

in the Jmeter 3.x. there are two steps to solve this problem.

Step 1, to modify the JVM memory in the JMeter batch file

```
##   ==============================================
##   Environment variables:
##   JVM_ARGS - optional java args, e.g. -Dprop=val
##
##   e.g.
##   JVM_ARGS="-Xms512m -Xmx512m" jmeter etc.
##
##   ==============================================
```

this is a default value in the jmeter.sh, according to your environment:

```
JVM_ARGS="-Xms512m -Xmx2048m"
```

in the jmeter.bat:

```
set JVM_ARGS=-Xms512m -Xmx2048m
```

Step 2, to Modify HEAP="-Xms512m -Xmx512m" in the JMeter batch file:

in the jmeter.sh

```
HEAP="-Xms512m -Xmx2048m"
```

in the jmeter.bat:

```
set HEAP=-Xms512m -Xmx2048m
```

Answer (score 2):

Open bin/jmeter.bat on windows or bin/jmeter.sh on linux,
find this line:

```
set HEAP=-Xms512m -Xmx512m
```

This variable is passed as arguments to jmeter at startup.
Increase the default heapsize like this:

```
set HEAP=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m
```

You could add more space if you have available and if jmeter needs more.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

also you should always consider running your test non-gui mode.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons why JMeter is consuming a lot of memory:

- Use and abuse of [UI Listeners](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html),
- **Running a test in UI mode**: run the test in batch mode instead
- **JMeter SaveService badly configured**: Are you saving requests and responses in JTL?
- **Too many threads** per JMeter load generator? Usually less than 1000 per engine should be okay, but it depends on the script complexity too. See [Remote Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) to run JMeter in **Distributed Mode**.

Tweaking the Heap is just one way to fix those issues:

`JVM_ARGS="-Xms512m -Xmx512m" jmeter.sh`

Check out [JMeter Out Of Memory: 12 Ways to Fix Them](https://octoperf.com/blog/2017/10/17/solve-jmeter-out-of-memory-issues/) for even more **valuable tips**.

Answer (score 0):

My one liner for this on a Mac (jmeter is bash script in this case):

$ JVM_ARGS="-Xms4g -Xmx4g -XX:NewSize=4g -XX:MaxNewSize=4g" && export JVM_ARGS && jmeter

Answer (score 0):

To set a higher JVM heap space, find your jmeter script (**/usr/share/jmeter/bin/jmeter** on Ubuntu when `jmeter` was installed through apt) and add the following line (found on https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%e2%80%9cout-memory%e2%80%9d-failure/) before the run_java line:

`HEAP="-Xms512m -Xmx4g"`

Here the maximum heap space was increased to 4GB.

However you might still run out of memory. This can happen when you run a lot of samples and you have a listener which collects data for each sample (for example **Listener -> View Results in Tree**). Remove this kind of (result) listener and focus on summarized result listeners (e.g. **Listener -> Summary Report**). This uses much less heap space, even for large stress tests.