# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 32756 bytes for ChunkPool::allocate

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

We have a **JMeter** test which stops in between giving the following error message

[image]

It runs fine when I run the tests with a load of 100,200 and 300 Users

I found one question [jmeter test failed with out of memory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20647651/jmeter-test-failed-with-out-of-memory-error) but that didn't help to solve the issue.

Have tried running this on machines with **12 GB RAM** and also with a **16 GB RAM**.

What could be the possible reason for it to behave so?

also tried to run on non-GUI mode even there the test stops.

[image: Non GUI mode]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to add the following piece of code in jmeter.bat ( Batch file )

```
set JVM_ARGS=-Xms512m -Xmx8000m
```

I added this in here

```
    if not defined HEAP (
    rem See the unix startup file for the rationale of the following parameters,
    rem including some tuning recommendations
    set HEAP=-Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=8000m 

)
set JVM_ARGS=-Xms512m -Xmx8000m
```

then it worked just fine.

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't run your test in GUI mode, as per first line of your terminal output you should be using [non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) for running your tests. GUI mode is for tests development or debugging only.
2. Make sure to use [64-bit Java JDK or Server JRE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html), you need to choose `Windows x64` option
3. [Increase your JVM Heap](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/e13814/jvm_tuning.htm#PERFM150) size by amending [HEAP environment variable](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) like:

   ```
   set HEAP=4G && jmeter.bat -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```
4. Make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and recommendations from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article

Comment: Let me try the non-GUI mode.

Comment: Oops! I am running Java 7 32 bit, let me change that and try again.

Answer (score 0):

As [Dimitri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51078414/3411556) mentions, don't use the GUI, it should only be used for testing or debugging. But this doesn't seem to be the issue for the OP.

In my case I got the issue 2 different times, with 2 different solutions:

1. I had been using the GUI for testing for a quiet a while and also had some of its output files opened, which were around a GB in total. Closing the GUI and those files gave me back enough memory to run via command line.
2. I increased the Heap size to 4GB and got error `The paging file is too small for this operation to complete`. So I upped the system's page file size and was able to run Jmeter. See [this link](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/increase-page-file-size-virtual-memory-windows) on how to up the page size of the system.